# Transitivity of almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Suppose an event $A$ occurs with probability $1$, and given that $A$ occured, event $B$ occurs with probability $1$. How does one formally prove that with probability $1$, event $B$ occurs? I understand what the statements mean , but I am struggling with proving it formally.
It came up in the context of recurrent states and communication classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(B) = P(B|A)P(A) + P(B|\tilde A)P( \tilde A)$

but if you know that $P(A)=1$ then $P(\tilde A)=0$ and so this simplifies to

$P(B) = P(B|A) = 1$